# Responsive Design Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a grid add columns when enough room is available for another one.  I have the code properly written to do this; but my issue is, how do I make a JavaScript event to constantly check to see if there if enough room to add a column.  This is easy in CSS using media queries, but I inherited this code, and it cannot be done in CSS.  So, I need a function for while a user is dragging the browser window border (to make the width larger), and inside of this function, do the responsive checking to see if a column can be added.  Does this make sense?  If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize

Comment: Would _Window's_ [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize) event do the trick?

Comment: Is it using jQuery-ui elements? If so, the drag event might be what you want

Comment: I have the resize binding, but he problem is, that (with the knowledge I have, but it is growing daily), when you first click on the browser window to drag it, this is when the 'resize' function runs. I am trying to get it to be responsive, like I have been looking at the jQuery function, 'mousemove'.  But I can't seem to get it to work properly.  Can anyone please attempt to give an answer with a fiddle or something.  Any help woul be appreciated.  thanks everyone again.

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event listener to the window resize

```
window.onresize = function() { 
    //do your thing
}
```

OR the newer (won't work in IE8 or lower, use `attachEvent` instead)

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() { 
    //do your thing 
})
```